# maven -> profile -> activation - all conditions are required or just one?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

**Configuration:**
- Maven: **3.0.5**
- Java: **1.6.0_45**

**Description:**

Let's say we have profile configuration like below:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-1</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.6</jdk>
            <property>
                <name>name</name>
                <value>Hubert</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-2</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.6</jdk>
            <property>
                <name>name</name>
                <value>Wiktoria</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

We have two profiles: *profile-1* and *profile-2*.

Profile *profile-1* should be active when two requirements are met:
    - jdk is version 1.6
    - property *name* has value *Hubert*

**Question:**

Let's check this configuration:

*mvn -Dname=Hubert help:active-profiles*

As a result I get that there are two active profiles: *profile-1* and *profile-2*.
Hmm...
Profile *profile-2* should not be active since property *name* has value different from expected *Wiktoria*.

Could someone explain me why this work like this? Is it a normal behavior?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the activation list with your trigger conditions is connected with `OR`. They do have a ticket to [provide multiple activation triggers](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3328), but it's still open.
That means, that it matches your sdk rule which is true and therefore active.

```
<profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <activation> <!-- true || true = true -->
        <jdk>1.6</jdk> <!-- true -->
        <property> <!-- true -->
            <name>name</name>
            <value>Hubert</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>profile-2</id>
    <activation> <!-- true || false = true -->
        <jdk>1.6</jdk> <!-- true -->
        <property> <!-- false -->
            <name>name</name>
            <value>Wiktoria</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Comment: That issue (MNG-3328) is here now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3328

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This is only a suplement to Chasmo's correct answer.

There is a book from sonatype describing Maven. In section [Sonatype book (section 5.3.1)](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html#profiles-sect-activation-config) we can find:

> A profile is activated when all activation criteria has been satisfied.

This is not true. Truth is that one condition is enought to activate profile, which is of course equal to OR logical condition. This behavior is described in [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation):

> Activation occurs when one or more of the specified criteria have been met. When the first positive result is encountered, processing stops and the profile is marked as active.

This is for me neither *intiutive* nor *very useful*. But thats how maven works at the time of writing that.

There is a ticket [MNG-4565](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565) for AND conjunction. This is marked as Bug, but acording to Maven doc it is not, so this ticket has been opened for almost 4 years. 
The most useful part is last comment to this ticket written by *Ronny Pscheidl*. His comment points to this source: [and-activation-profile-selector](https://github.com/johnjcool/and-activation-profile-selector). This changes default maven OR condition to AND condition. Tested. Works. But of course if you decide to use this, you have one more thing to remember of.

Comment: MNG-4565 has been fixed in 3.2.2.